Discord bot not responding to slash commands
I'm having trouble with my Discord bot not responding to slash commands. I've implemented the interactionCreate event handler and am using the discord.js library.
Here's my relevant code:
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials, InteractionType, Permissions, SlashCommandBuilder, Collection } = require('discord.js');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const fs = require('fs');

dotenv.config();

const token = process.env.TOKEN;
const clientId = process.env.CLIENT_ID;
const guildId = process.env.GUILD_ID;

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates,
  ],
  partials: [Partials.Channel],
});

client.commands = new Collection();

const commandsPath = './commands';
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const filePath = `./commands/${file}`;
  const command = require(filePath);
  if ('data' in command && typeof command.data === 'object') {
    if ('toJSON' in command.data) {
      client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
    } else {
      console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "toJSON" export.`);
    }
  } else {
    console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" export.`);
  }
}

console.log('Starting bot...');

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);

  const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildId);
  guild.commands.set(client.commands.map(command => command.data))
    .then(() => console.log('Slash commands registered successfully.'))
    .catch(console.error);
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
  // Filter out non-command interactions
  if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

  const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

  if (!command) return;

  try {
    await command.execute(interaction);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error handling interaction ${interaction.commandName}:`, error);
    if (interaction.replied || interaction.deferred) {
      await interaction.followUp({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
    } else {
      await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
    }
  }
});

client.login(token);


I've encountered an issue where my Discord bot is not responding to slash commands. I've implemented the interactionCreate event handler and am using the discord.js library to handle slash commands.
I expected the bot to respond to slash commands with the appropriate actions, but it's not triggering any responses.
I've tried the following troubleshooting steps:

Ensuring the bot is online and has the necessary permissions.
Checking the slash command registration process.
Verifying the interactionCreate event handler logic.
Testing with different slash commands to isolate the issue.

